# How Can I Remove The Left Side Of Microsoft Outlook After Forced Update To Windows 11?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After being forced to "upgrade" my computer to Windows 11, I have noticed many negative changes to UI across all apps. One example is Outlook-- does anyone know how to remove the left side of the below image (to the left of "file")?

[image]

[image]

Note: I use MS365 for Enterprise, Version 2211, Build 15831.20190

Comment: You are not forced to upgrade to Windows 11. You have 10 days to go back to Windows 10.

Comment: I assume you have Office 365, and that means you likely recently had Outlook 365, as an update to Windows 10 from Windows 11 wouldn't change the interface of Outlook otherwise. It looks like that navigation bar is just minimized. Rolling back an Office 365 build isn't trivial but more information would be required before an answer could be generated

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, not understanding. Basically the image shows everything just shifted to the right from what I previously had. "Favorites, Inbox, Sent Items" were the left-most part of my screen. Is there a way to get back to that view? Currently it is just those icons 6 and vertical whitespace with everything else shifted right

Comment: You are talking about the `app bar` the current consensus since Microsoft made this a permanent change is [this approach using a regedit](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/7190-outlook-move-navigation-bar-left-to-bottom.html). Reccomend backing up registry prior to making any change.  On the road but will write this up as an answer when back at a PC.

Comment: 2207 is from July 2022. So what build are you running, instead of a comment, edit your question. I will repeat this change you have discovered has nothing to do with your upgrade to Windows 11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Update:***

Based on my research, i found a [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/308958/2021-outlook-email-navigation-pane-on-left-interfe.html) mentioned the below steps is useful, please try this as @Vik99977-6185 posted:
[image]

---

Please try to uncheck **Show Apps in Outlook** option via File>Options>Advanced:
[image]

And then restart Outlook.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Hi Christy, sorry, but this was already unchecked for me. Just to be sure I rechecked and the unchecked again before restarting, but no luck

Comment: Hi @EDS! I have updated my reply above and please try the suggested solution.

Comment: That did it, thanks again!

Comment: This seems to work for me, but I'm wary of the info text for that option.  It says turning it off will "snooze" the new UI changes, suggesting that they'll return at some random time in the future.  (I've got Office 2019, so I was surprised this morning when the UI changed.  I assumed they would leave the old versions alone and focus on Office 365.)

Answer (score 1):

Outlook (365 and like) on Windows 11 still works like classic Outlook. I have this here. Windows 11 did not change settings on me.

Right Click on Navigation Options (from your screen above) and select (enable) compact Navigation.

Check View settings for compact navigation.

Then Ribbon across the top, Outlook Folder Tree down the left, and Mail, Calendar, People icons are just small icons bottom left.

Works here just fine.

See Screen Shot

[image: Outlook Compact Navigation]

.

Also use the Classic Ribbon.  Facilitates overall compact Outlook.

[image: Classic Ribbon]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see "navigation options" or "compact navigation" anywhere in the settings or options. Actually, looks like it's impossible to change based on this: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/outlook-navigation-pane-on-the-left

Comment: It is not all impossible to change. Please see my screen shot of compact Outlook 365 on Windows 11 Pro

Comment: You can also use Classic Menu (answer amended) as that facilitates overall compact Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think you can edit because you still have that "Coming Soon" in the top right according to that link. I have the classic ribbon and compact navigation under view->View Settings, but no luck

Comment: "Coming Soon" is part of the Ribbon and does not affect Size.  I just disable Coming Soon.  Classic Ribbon is in the Ribbon Pull Down where I showed.  You may need to reinstall Office if the standard things are not there for you.

Comment: There is another thing to be wary of.  Outlook has a setting (Options) to keep Setting in the Cloud. I do this and I can up Outlook on a new machine in less than 5 minutes.  If you turned this ON or let it be ON and you are unhappy with the settings, you need to review all the view and navigation settings.  That may have happened to you.

Comment: If you run into big problems. open Outlook, go to Options, General, near the top, and uncheck (disable) Store my Outlook settings in the Cloud. OK to this.  Close Outlook, uninstall Office, Restart, and set up Outlook again. BEWARE. This means setting up accounts and folders again. Try NOT to do this except as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to restore the Classic Outlook version, with Navigation options on the bottom. I found the info on https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-global-customer-service/new-location-for-the-mail-calendar-people-and-other-modules/ba-p/3596278

Open Outlook Options, Advanced tab where you can uncheck Show Apps in Outlook, then restart Outlook to return to the classic navigation bar.